# Programmatically creating a view

Tags: views, 8

We have a custom table that creates a mixed listing of custom entity and core entity which is needed for the project.

Could someone provide a code example for programmatically creating a view in drupal 8 with mixed entities with a custom query?

I have reviewed Drupal 7 examples out there and they don't seem sufficient.

The goal is to use views powerful field formatting and reordering capability, rather than reinventing that wheel for our custom table display.